# Is it possible to extract a string from a selected TMetropolisUIListBoxItem's Title, Subtitle or Description properties?

Tags: delphi, listboxitem

I'm creating an app that uses Metropolis UI Listbox Items and I want to transfer the Description parameter of a selected item to a Memo with a button click. In regular listbox items it's easy to extract the Text string, for example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
    Memo1.Text := ListBox1.Selected.Text;
      end;
```

This also works on the Text property of a Metropolis UI Listbox Item, as normal.
However, if I try the same thing with the Title, Subtitle or Description properties, it just doesn't work.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
    Memo1.Text := ListBox1.Selected.Description;
      end;
```

Does anybody knows how can I use the strings on those properties in the way I intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cast the listbox item to the metropolis listbox item you can access the properties.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lbItemSel: TListBoxItem;
begin
  lbItemSel := ListBox1.Selected;
  if (lbItemSel is TMetropolisUIListBoxItem) then
  begin
    Memo1.Text := 
     TMetropolisUIListBoxItem(lbItemSel).Title + ' ' +
     TMetropolisUIListBoxItem(lbItemSel).SubTitle + ' ' +
     TMetropolisUIListBoxItem(lbItemSel).Description
     ;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't test the class name. Use the `is` operator, `if lbItemSel is TMetropolisUIListBoxItem then` which also removes the need for testing against `nil`.